# Quiero comparar 2 fechas con carbón laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

lo que necesito es comparar 2 fechas la de año actual y la de vigencia  si el mes del año actual es menor al mes del año de vigencia entonces que me reste uno a $diferencia y si el mes del actual es igual al mes del año de vigencia entonces que me pase a otra condicion de dias y si el dia es menor entonces que me reste uno a $diferencia

esta es mi funcion

```
public static function dias_pendientes($id){


        $fecha_actual= Carbon::now();

        $vigencia = Empleado::select('vigencia')->where('id', $id)->first()->vigencia;

        $fechaVigencia = Carbon::parse($vigencia);

        $diferencia = $fechaVigencia->diffInYears($fecha_actual);

hasta aqui me funciona pero no se como podria compara el mes del año actual con el mes de vigencia de mi empleado



        return $diferencia;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Para comparar las fechas con `Carbon`, la clase proporciona métodos muy útiles:

```
//Igual a    
    var_dump($first->eq($second));                     // bool(false)
    var_dump($first->equalTo($second));                // bool(false)
    var_dump($first == $second);                       // bool(false)

//Diferente a...    
    var_dump($first->ne($second));                     // bool(true)
    var_dump($first->notEqualTo($second));             // bool(true)
    var_dump($first != $second);                       // bool(true)

//Mayor que...    
    var_dump($first->gt($second));                     // bool(false)
    var_dump($first->greaterThan($second));            // bool(false)
    var_dump($first->isAfter($second));                // bool(false)
    var_dump($first > $second);                        // bool(false)

//Mayor ó igual que...    
    var_dump($first->gte($second));                    // bool(false)
    var_dump($first->greaterThanOrEqualTo($second));   // bool(false)
    var_dump($first >= $second);                       // bool(false)


//Menor que... 
    var_dump($first->lt($second));                     // bool(true)
    var_dump($first->lessThan($second));               // bool(true)
    var_dump($first->isBefore($second));               // bool(true)
    var_dump($first < $second);                        // bool(true)

//Menor o igual que...
    var_dump($first->lte($second));                    // bool(true)
    var_dump($first->lessThanOrEqualTo($second));      // bool(true)
    var_dump($first <= $second);                       // bool(true)
```

En tu caso, para saber si la fecha actual es mayor que la vigencia, tendrías que hacer esto, por ejemplo:

```
if($fecha_actual->gt($fechaVigencia)){

}
```

Claramente para que estos métodos funcionen correctamente, ambas variables de fecha deben de ser una instancia de la clase `Carbon`.

Comment: gracias ahora lo que necesito es hacer un case con un for en el cual el for me va a tomar el valor de $vigencia y si sale uno me sume 15 a una variable y si sale dos me sume 18 a otro y si no es niguna me sume 30

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir, si tienes alguna otra duda, asegúrate primero de investigar e intentar algo por tu cuenta y si aún tienes dudas, abre otra pregunta, también, si esta respuesta resolvió tu cuestión, asegúrate de marcarla como la respuesta correcta.